# HOW TO ADD life_date IN REPORT?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

**I want to add the expiry date from the number of lot in the report of the Bon de livraison in odoo, but nothing shows even if i add the field life_date.
Can you please help me to fix this.**

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-sm mt48" t-if="o.move_line_ids and o.state=='done'">
                        <t t-set="has_serial_number" t-value="o.move_line_ids.mapped('lot_id')" />
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><strong>Article</strong></th>
                                <th class="text-center"><strong>Quantité</strong></th>
                                <th name="lot_serial" t-if="has_serial_number" groups="stock.group_lot_on_delivery_slip">
                                    Lot/numéro de série
                                </th>
                                <th name="life_date" t-if="life_date" groups="product_expiry.life_date">
                                    Date d'expiration du lot
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr t-foreach="o.move_line_ids" t-as="move_line">
                                <td>
                                    <span t-field="move_line.product_id"/>
                                    <p t-if="o.picking_type_code == 'outgoing'">
                                        <span t-field="move_line.product_id.sudo().description_pickingout"/>
                                    </p>
                                    <p t-if="o.picking_type_code == 'incoming'">
                                        <span t-field="move_line.product_id.sudo().description_pickingin"/>
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span t-field="move_line.qty_done"/>
                                    <span t-field="move_line.product_uom_id"/>
                                </td>
                                <td t-if="has_serial_number and move_line.lot_name" groups="stock.group_lot_on_delivery_slip">
                                    <span t-field="move_line.lot_name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td t-else="" groups="stock.group_lot_on_delivery_slip">
                                    <span t-field="move_line.lot_id.name"/>
                                </td>
                                <td t-if="life_date and move_line.life_date" groups="product_expiry.life_date">
                                    <span t-field="move_line.life_date"/>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you check if the user login in have this group *life_date* or not?

Comment: emm actually there is no group with this name.

Comment: Can you check this line in your XML file **<th name="life_date" t-if="life_date" groups="product_expiry.life_date">
                                    Date d'expiration du lot
                                </th>**

Comment: I replaced the group with group_production_lot but still dont work

Comment: You can check if **life_date** fields not False in yore database before printing